# Switching Java 11 for Java 8 on the server

Tags: java, linux, bash

So I've seen a bunch of tutorials on switching from Java 8 to Java 11, but I actually need to do the opposite. And I am doing it on a server, so I can use only bash.
[image]

I am pretty clueless of how to do it. Any help?

Comment: 1) Install Java 8; e.g. using `sudo apt install ....`  2) Use `set-alternatives` to make Java 8 the default.  (For more information ... I expect that those tutorials that you saw explained how to install Java and use `set-alternatives`.)

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly. And when asking such questions, please do not forget to add the needed information. Of course we can guess what OS you are using by looking at the output message of `java --version`, but it would be much easier and more useful to state it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this command and chose version java:

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

Comment: Are you sure that will also switch all the other executables (e.g. `jar`, `javap` etc.) over to the other version too?

Comment: Of course since the path to your java environment variable will be changed any impact related to it will also change

Comment: I think you'll find that's not the case if you investigate. Also, `update-alternatives` works on symlinks and that java "environment variables" are only set explicitly on Debian-based systems, so could not come into the equation. It certainly doesn't for me (using *actual* Debian) switch between versions in a wholesale manner. It just switches *one executable*

Comment: I will learn more about your case, hope you find the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do on my Debian system:

`alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-full-amd64;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'`

This will ensure *all* executables are of the same version, and is a lot easier than `update-alternatives`, even if it *did* work (see my comments below another answer) or `update-java-alternatives` and is less error-prone

Answer (score 1):

I use this tool  [SdkMan Install](https://sdkman.io/install), [SkMan manual](https://sdkman.io/usage)

```
skd list java
```

print the versions of java available, and you can install it with comands like

```
sdk install java 8.0.292.hs-adpt
```

After you install a java version with sdkman set the java Home with

```
export JAVA_HOME=~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

you can install many java versions as you want and set your default version with

```
sdk default java 8.0.292.hs-adpt
```

If you use maven or gradle install them from sdkman, because in this way autodetects the version switching.

If you want to switch java versions only for specific projects check the env and .sdkmanrc part in the manual. It switches versions when you cd into a directory and go back to default when you cd out.